# Docker compose not updating images after change

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a yml file for docker compose to create two containers and connect them.
I made some changes to the code today(replaced a folder to be added in one of the docker files).Here's the yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - web:/www

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    restart: always
    links:
     - web
    volumes:
     - web:/www
volumes:
    web:
```

The change I made was to the dockerfile in ./web:

```
FROM python:3.6.4

RUN mkdir /www
WORKDIR /www
ADD . /www/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python /www/davidbien/manage.py migrate
CMD cd dockertest && gunicorn dockertest.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
```

The change I made was to change the /davidbien/ folder name from dockertest folder.

I tried rebuilding images by running:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

But this did not help.
I also tried the same command without --no-cache.
I also tried :

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

After rebuilding but when I run the script I don't know why the old folder still appears(even though it's removed).
What else can I do to clear the cache in docker-compose? I googled that but only got the above two commands.
Thanks

Comment: Can you put up your yml compose file along with what you changed specifically? It's not possible to help you without any context.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I totally missed that. Edited my post.

Comment: did you try `docker-compose down` before up?

Comment: Mike docker-compose will recognize there’s new image in local registry and will automatically recreate the container unless you specifically did a restart instead of up. Anyway, docker-compose has no cache, it just wraps docker commands (run, stop etc.)

Comment: I tried running `docker-compose down --rmi all` to remove all images. After that I rebuilt them using `docker-compose build --no-cache` and up at the end. Still the same result. This is really weird as the folder `dockertest` has been removed so I'm guessing it's being cached. I also tried restarting my machine but still nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the quickest way I manage to solve this and get my containers updated is by changing their names.

So, I had a container named `app` and it's settings in `app.docker`. I renamed this to `php` and `php.docker` respectively. Running `docker-composer up -d` created the updated containers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem problem were anonymous volumes:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4337#issuecomment-356480788

These are reused and so the data is not updated. You can do

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down -v`

which will delete also all volumes and the caching behaviour is gone.

Comment: But I want to keep the volumes

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by adding a build flag with docker compose:

```
docker compose down
docker compose up --build
```

Courtesy: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1487#issuecomment-391455175